# desktop+ not saving term/shell buffer

Tags: shell, desktop, session

For session management, I was happy with inbuilt `desktop.el` except that it could not retain the term/shell buffers. Everytime I quit emacs, it asked to kill the term/shells. Then I read the ability of desktop+ to retain the term/shell, thus installed it through `M-x package-install` after going through its [github doc](https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus).
I removed the line `desktop-save-mode` from `init` file to stop loading the `desktop.el` sessions. Also, as suggested in the github page I have put

```
(setq desktop+-special-buffer-handlers
  '(term-mode
    compilation-mode
    org-agenda-mode
    indirect-buffer
    Man-mode
    shell-mode))
```

in the init file..

**I have 2 questions**

1. In new emacs session (having term/shell windows), I saved the session with `desktop+create`, verified its existence on the disk, but when quitting emacs, in `minibuffer`, I still get the same message as with desktop (to kill the running processes i.e. the term/shell buffers).
   How can I retain the session term/shell windows as mentioned in the doc?
2. Another question is that I need to `desktop+load` after opening emacs to load the session even of the default dir. What can I add in the init file to load the default session and not a blank emacs. I tried `desktop+-save-mode 1` as implicitly mentioned in the github page but this gives as error loading the init file.
   Even puttting `(require 'desktop+)` does not load the saved session.

Before asking here, I opened an issue on the [github](https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus/issues/27), but it hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here?  If you start processes inside Emacs and then kill Emacs, you will kill the inferior processes.  The desktop.el library can't keep those processes running and then reattach them to a new Emacs session, any more than it could resurrect the original Emacs process.

Comment: From the looks of https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus/commit/10c49a6c653221d28291e0efcf62339a94a2e481#diff-1f77a240e9315a4d23059a25d002c5dfaa21850a3168199c12f45f86362fccd8R325-R331 the functionality is very limited.

Comment: I am expecting emacs to retain the term/shell windows at least. That's what [desktop+](https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus) is stating in point no 2 `Desktop sessions by default save only buffers associated to "real" files. Desktop+ extends this by handling also "special buffers". The list of currently supported special buffer types is:

compilation buffers (in compilation-mode)
terminal buffers (in term-mode)
org agenda & todo lists (in org-agenda-mode)
indirect buffers (a.k.a clones).
man pages (in Man-mode)
shell buffers (in shell-mode)`

Comment: I am not expecting it to retain the running processes in the shell/term like tmux, as there is no running processes inside shell at the time of exiting emacs. emacs (or desktop.el) considers the idle term/shell buffers as running processes and asks to kill at the time of exiting. I am just expecting to save and reload the term/shell buffers (& its respective windows) as mentioned in the desktop+. Is there some other way to do that within emacs?

Comment: The link in my previous comment indicates that it won't save/restore buffer contents.  Offhand I can't help with any alternatives, sorry (it's not something I've ever wanted to do), so hopefully someone else can make a suggestion.  My best suggestion is to look at the desktop+ code and see if you can contribute an enhancement back which would do the things you want.

Comment: In the same link, isn't the added line 320 onwards, saving the shell buffer? desktop+ is also referred on [emacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement) for session management.

Comment: Quoting that code: "Currently, it saves and restores the current working directory.  The text in the buffer, as well as environment variables, shell
variables and other state are lost."  I've never used it, so I can't tell you what it actually *does* do, but it seems clear about what it *doesn't* do.